# Archive Option for ADO projects

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to archive projects in Azure DevOps. we would like to hide the project from the organization home page and don't want to delete it.

I don't find any related articles about the same, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to archive projects in Azure DevOps.

Sorry to say, there's no such feature supported in Azure DevOps. The repository has been hosted on Azure Devops. It can be look as a achieved project.

There has been lots of users who has the same demand with you. They have been raised one feature suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365495/add-a-nice-way-to-archive-tfs-projects.html.

**Note:** You can vote and add your comments for this suggestion. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously